# phonegap ajax not working with value

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({url: "http://somedomain/app/district.php", success: function(result){
    $("#district").html(result);
    }});

    $.ajax({url: "http://somedomain/app/category.php", success: function(result){
    $("#crop-category").html(result);
    }});

        $('#district').change(function(){
    var value=$('#district').val();
    $('#upazila').parent().find('span').html("<span>&nbsp;</span>");
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://somedomain/app/upazila.php",
      type: "get", //send it through get method
      data:{value},
      success: function(response) {
        $("#upazila").html(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
      }
    });

});

    });

</script>
```

this is my jquery code, and im build android an app.
for the first 2 ajax request i got value, but when i pass some variable through get request the code doesn't work. in debug mood it says
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } index.html:36
which is

**data:{value},**

but it works fine on browser...
please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your third `ajax` call, `data` field is not a valid object, `data` **should be an object , string or Array**.  Pass the `value` as shown below :

```
data: value
```

You need not mention it inside the flower brackets. Or if it is a string or array and you want it to be passed as an object , pass it as shown below:

```
data: {value: value}
```